# Using Jest Mock API Calls to SetState

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, axios, enzyme

I have an API call which runs whenever a certain component mounts.  If this API call is successful the response data is used to update the state of one of my React Hooks.

The issue I am having is either related to asynchronicity or a poorly formatted mock API call, but no matter what I try I cannot get this test to work.

Here is a simplified version of the API:

```
const getOrg =() => {
  axios.get(URL, config)
    .then(response => response.data)
    .then(data => {
       setOrgTitle(data.name)
    }
}
```

Basically the API is triggered and my `setOrgTitle` hook is updated from the response.

```
const [orgTitle, setOrgTitle] = useState("");
```

Now in my return statement I am displaying the value of `orgTitle`:

```
<h1 className={styles.titleText} id="document-folders-h1">
  {orgTitle} Folders
</h1>
```

Alright, so the component is pretty simple. When I am trying to test things my two ideas were to either set the initial `orgTitle` hook state in my test or to mock the API.  After some research I decided mocking the API was the way to go.

So I have a `mockAxios` component:

```
const mockAxios = {
  get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} }))
};

module.exports = mockAxios;
```

And my test file:

```
import mockAxios from "../../mockTests/DocumentFoldersMock";

it("fetches results for getAdminOrg", () => {
  axios.get.mockImplementation(() =>
    Promise.resolve({ data: { name: "GETtest" } })
  );
  const wrapper = mount(
    <AppProviders>
      <DocumentFolders />
    </AppProviders>
  );
  const orgTitle = wrapper.find("#document-folders-h1");
  expect(orgTitle.text()).toContain("GETtest Folders");
});
```

I am mocking the response data, however I am not sure how to run the `setOrgTitle` function which is called in the `.then` of my actual axios call.  How can I do this from my mock axios call using my mock response?

The result of the Jest test says expected("GETtest Folders") received(" Folders") so I am pretty sure that I am either having an issue with asynchronicity or an issue calling the hook update.

Comment: Are you asking how to make sure that `setOrgTitle` was called? Because to me it looks like you're already doing that in your test by looking for the text with the name, which would only display if it was actually fetched. Or is your test failing?

Comment: @Mikaela the test is failing so I am assuming setOrgTitle is not getting called.  The Jest response says expected("GETtest Folders") received(" Folders").  I am just stuck trying to figure out if I am having an async issue or if the problem is with my mock API

Comment: I see! How are you overriding Axios? You import your mock, but is your hook actually calling it? Even if it's an async issue that makes the test fail (unmounting before the text updates for example), the `get` method should still be called. You could also try using [axios-mock-adapter](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter) to mock Axios in your tests.

Comment: That's a good question and I am not entirely sure how or if the mock is actually being called.  I tried to replicate the format others have used to mock an API call which occurs in `useEffect`, but now that I look deeper I am not sure my mock function is being called at all.

Comment: You could try just logging something in the mocked `get` method to see if it is ever called. [You can read more about mocks in Jest here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks).